# Do all USB-C compatible devices have USB hubs inside of them?

Tags: usb, usb-device, usb-c

Since the signals on the USB-C connector are mirrored on each side with the CC pins indicating the plug orientation, does this mean that all USB-C devices have USB hubs so they can use the right D+/D- pair, or the right superspeed RX/TX pair?

Answer (score 2):

No, USB-C devices don't have to have USB hubs inside. The mirroring capability of Type-C connector is provided by a multiplexer, either embedded into the controller chip (at the expense of doubling super-speed interface pins), or using an external multiplexer IC like [TI HD3S3212](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/hd3ss3212.pdf):

[image]

Both sides of USB 2.0 data lines are simply connected in parallel at Type-C connector.